# What's This Blue Dome Projected Over My Back?

Tags: torchlight-2, torchlight-2-engineer

I've just noticed that my Engineer suddenly has this blue dome thing coming out of his pack and hanging in the air over his back.  What is this?  Is it put there by the 'Aegis' skill, the effects of which is currently active (apparently)?

[image: Blue dome on my Engineer's back]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That glow is the shield projected by the Aegis of Fate passive skill, from the Aegis skill tree.